# Is v-autocomplete compatible with Google Places Autocomplete API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, autocomplete, google-places-api, vuetify.js

I try to utilize [Google Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) to populate [Vuetify Autocomplete Component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes) as follows:

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    ref="autocomplete" 
    label="Location"
  >
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(this.$refs.autocomplete),
      {types: ['geocode']})
  }
}
</script>
```

However, in the developer console of the browser, it throws an error:

> InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement

My guess is `v-autocomplete` is not of type [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

(And it was not only the case for `v-autocomplete`: replacing it with [`v-input`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/inputs) ends up with the same error, too.)

Is there a way to make `v-autocomplete` filled with Google Places Autocomplete API, like making it an instance of `HTMLInputElement` manually or so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems no direct way of both keeping material look of `v-autocomplete` when merely using `google.maps.places.Autocomplete`. To achieve that, I wrapped the `getPlacePredictions()` method of the API -not a component- called [Autocomplete **Service**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-autocomplete-service):

> PlacesUtils.js

```
/* global google */

const GetSuggestions = async searchText => {
  let result

  try {
    const rawResult = await searchLocation(searchText)
    result = rawResult.map((res) => {
      return {
        id: res.place_id,
        value: res.description
      }
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred', err)
    result = null
  }
  return result
}

// Auxiliary functions
// wrap google api's callback to an async function
const searchLocation = async val => {
  let promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var displaySuggestions = (predictions, status) => {
      if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        reject(status)
      }
      resolve(predictions)
    }

    var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()
    service.getPlacePredictions({
      input: val,
      types: ['geocode']
    },
    displaySuggestions)
  }).catch(function (err) { throw err })

  return promise
}

export { GetSuggestions }
```

Then, adding a `watch` for the model of `v-autocomplete` I call this method on change made by the user as follows:

> Place.vue

```
<template>
  <v-layout row justify-center>
    <!-- ... -->
      <v-autocomplete
        label="Location"
        v-model="autocompleteLocationModel"
        :items="locationFoundItems"
        :search-input.sync="locationSearchText"
        item-text="value"
        item-value="id"
        hide-no-data
        return-object
      >
    </v-autocomplete>
    <!-- ... -->
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint handle-callback-err: "warn" */
import { GetSuggestions } from '@/utils/PlaceUtils'

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      autocompleteLocationModel: null,
      locationSearchText: null,
      locationEntries: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    locationFoundItems () {
      return this.locationEntries
    }
  },
  watch: {
    locationSearchText (newVal) {
      var _vue = this

      // If less than 3 chars typed, do not search
      if (!newVal || newVal.length <= 3) return

      // Call the method from the previous section here
      GetSuggestions(newVal)
        .then(function (res) {
          _vue.locationEntries = res
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          // error handling goes here
        })
    }
  }
  // ...
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm messing around with this now as well and have it partially working and will update when I get it fully flushed out, but here's the problem with your code now.

When you are applying `ref="autocomplete"` in your template, you are applying the `ref` to the component not the input. To get it to work, I set an `id="autocomplete"` which gets applied to the input directly, created a variable in my mounted function to reference the input id, then I pass that into the autocomplete function.  I updated your code below to reflect this.

```
<template>
  <v-autocomplete
    id="autocomplete" 
    label="Location"
  >
  </v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    var autocompleteInput = document.querySelector('#autocomplete');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(autocompleteInput),
      {types: ['geocode']})
  }
}
</script>
```

You can apply the same principle to a `v-text field`, but the google autocomplete results will appear in their own container below the input rather than in the select dropdown container like `v-autocomplete`.

Comment: Fine workaround, but pity it distorts the `v-autocomplete` look.

Answer (score 1):

@vahdet I wanted to thank you for your code in which I used as a complete component that emits selected place details  on "place" Thank you for your help!

```
<template>
  <v-layout row justify-center>
    <!-- ... -->
    <v-autocomplete
      label="Location"
      id="decoy"
      v-model="autocompleteLocationModel"
      :items="locationFoundItems"
      :search-input.sync="locationSearchText"
      item-text="value"
      item-value="id"
      hide-no-data
      return-object
    >
    </v-autocomplete>
    <!-- ... -->
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
/* eslint handle-callback-err: "warn" */
import { GetSuggestions } from "../../../PlacesUtils";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      autocompleteLocationModel: null,
      locationSearchText: null,
      locationEntries: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    locationFoundItems() {
      return this.locationEntries;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    autocompleteLocationModel(newVal) {
      console.log(newVal.id);
      let resplace = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(
        document.getElementById("decoy")
      );

      resplace.getDetails(
        {
          placeId: newVal.id
        },
        (x) => {
          this.$emit("place", x);
        }
      );
    },

    locationSearchText(newVal) {
      var _vue = this;

      // If less than 3 chars typed, do not search
      if (!newVal || newVal.length <= 3) return;

      // Call the method from the previous section here
      GetSuggestions(newVal)
        .then(function(res) {
          _vue.locationEntries = res;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          // error handling goes here
          console.log(err);
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```